# how to extract this data in .JSON

Tags: python

Code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import requests

url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/infosimples-public/commercia/case/product.html#'

resposta_final = {}
response = requests.get(url)
parsed_html = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
resposta_final['url'] = parsed_html.select_one('div.company-name span').get_text()
```

Result as a json:

```
{
    "url": "Commercia"
}
```

This address should be in place of "Commercia":
https://storage.googleapis.com/infosimples-public/commercia/case/product.html

Comment: Can you post more code? A minimal reproducible example please? Including which modules you're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want to have `https://storage.googleapis.com/infosimples-public/commercia/case/product.html` instead of `Commercia`.

Just do this:

```py
json = {"url": "Commercia"}

json["url"] = "https://storage.googleapis.com/infosimples-public/commercia/case/product.html"
print(json)
```

Output

```
{'url': 'https://storage.googleapis.com/infosimples-public/commercia/case/product.html'}
```